# How to write a contains method for linked lists using recursion? java

Tags: java, methods, recursion, linked-list

I need to write a contains method using recursion, meaning finding whether 'element' exists in one of the nodes.

```
    public class SortedSetNode implements Set 
    {
        protected String value;
        protected SortedSetNode next;
    }

    public boolean contains(String el) {         

        if (next.getValue().equals(el))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            next.contains(el);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You probably need to override your `contains` method seeing as your class implements `java.util.set` and that class has a `contains` method as well

Comment: Using recursion in that context is a weird requirement: if the list is large enough and the item is close to the end you will get a StackOverflowError (10k elements should be enough to break it)...

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean contains(String el) {
   if (value.equals(el)) return true;
   if (next == null) return false;
   else return next.contains(el); 
}
```

Comment: return `false` not `dalse`

Comment: @Smac89 - he might have defined `dalse` as a constant :-)

Comment: @StephenC

ahh True true. But constants should be capitalised?

Answer (score 0):

well `next.contains(el)`, just add a return statement before that!

```
if (value.equals(el)) {
   return true;
}

return next.contains(el);
```

and of course you have to deal with when `next` is invalid (i.e you're at the last element), then return false.

Comment: It'll throw NullPointerException if `next` is null (string not found)

Comment: that's why there's the last sentence of my answer :)

Comment: I've corrected to this:
    `public boolean contains(String el) { `
      
     `if (next != null)`
     `{
      return false;
     }
     else if (next.getValue().equals(el))
     {
      return true;
     }
     else
     {
      return next.contains(el);
     }
     
    }`

Comment: not going to work. ``if (next != null) {return false;}`` means you return false if there's a next element. Try to think as a human how you would do it, write the basic steps and their order on paper and then transform that into code. Or alfasin's code also works